# Multithreaded QuickSort

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pointers, pthreads

Sorry for the previous question.
As I am new comer , I was unaware about how to post a question on stack overflow .
So here is the code of multithreade quick sort I have done using Pthread.
But It is not working Properly.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#define max 20
using namespace std;
class quick
{
    int arr[max];
    int n;

    public:

   int high;
    int low;
    quick(int n1)
    {
      n=n1;
    }
    quick(quick *obj)
    {

        this->n=obj->n;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<this->n;i++)
        {
            this->arr[i]=obj->arr[i];
        }
    }
    void accept();
    void display();
    void quicksort(int,int);
    int partition(int,int);
    static void* thread_function(void *ptr)
    {
            quick* q= static_cast<quick *>(ptr);
        q->quicksort(q->low,q->high);
    }
};

void quick :: accept()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter data: "<<endl;
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

}

void quick :: display()
{
    int i;
    cout<<"The array is: "<<endl;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    cout<<endl;
}

void quick :: quicksort(int low,int high)
{


    int piv_index;
    pthread_t th1,th2;
    quick *q1,*q2;
    if(low<high)
    {
        piv_index=partition(low,high);


        q1= new quick(this);
        q2= new quick(this);

        q1->low=low;
        q1->high=piv_index-1;
        q2->low=piv_index+1;
        q2->high=high;

        void *obj1=reinterpret_cast<void *>(q1);
        void *obj2=reinterpret_cast<void *>(q2);

        pthread_create(&th1,NULL,quick :: thread_function,(void *)obj1);
        pthread_create(&th2,NULL,quick :: thread_function,(void *)obj2);

        pthread_join(th1,NULL);
        pthread_join(th2,NULL);
    }

}

int quick :: partition(int low,int high)
{
    int i,j,pivot,temp;

    pivot=arr[low];
    i=low+1;
    j=high;

    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(arr[i]<=pivot)
            i++;

        while(arr[j]>pivot)
            j--;

        if(i<j)
        {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
        }
    }
    arr[low]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=pivot;

    return j;
}

int main()
{
    int no;
    cout<<"Enter the size of array: "<<endl;
    cin>>no;
    quick *q;
    q= new quick(no);
    q->accept();
    cout<<"Before Sorting: "<<endl;
    q->display();
    q->low=0;
    q->high=no-1;
    void *ptr=reinterpret_cast<void *>(q);
    quick::thread_function(ptr);

    cout<<"After Sorting: "<<endl;
    q->display();



    return 0;
}


    output:
Enter the size of array: 
5
Enter data: 
5
Enter data: 
4
Enter data: 
3
Enter data: 
2
Enter data: 
1
Before Sorting: 
The array is: 
5 4 3 2 1 
After Sorting: 
The array is: 
1 4 3 2 5
```

Kindly Help Me to figure out what is exactly the mistake...
Thank You In advance

Comment: "*It is not working properly*" - You could greatly improve the question by adding what the the problem is exactly. Of course it is not working properly, otherwise you would not be asking. What did you expect to happen? And what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given these definitions:

```
void *obj1=reinterpret_cast<void *>(q1);
void *obj2=reinterpret_cast<void *>(q2);
```

It looks like you're casting a void** to a void* below. I don't think you mean to be doing that:

```
pthread_create(&th1,NULL,quick :: thread_function,(void *)&obj1);
pthread_create(&th2,NULL,quick :: thread_function,(void *)&obj2);
```

Remove the ampersands and see if that helps.

EDIT:

Also, it looks like your constructor for `quick` is copying the array from the source object, and I don't see anything copying it back to the original object, so those results are getting lost. It would be better to store the array separately and pass a pointer to it from one `quick` to the next, so that they all operate on the same copy of the data.

EDIT(2):

The quick and dirty way:

Move `int arr[max];` from `quick` to inside `main`. Place `int *arr;` into `quick`. Change the constructors like so:

```
quick(int n1, int *a)
{
  n=n1;
  arr = a;
}
quick(quick *obj)
{
    this->n=obj->n;
    this->arr = obj->arr;
}
```

Finally, change the `q` assignment in `main` to `q= new quick(no, arr);`